# How to make freeradius authenticate with CHAP instead with PAP

Tags: radius, freeradius

I i have installed freeradius 3 on server, and i have try to test chap by

```
radtest -t chap ahmed test localhost 1812 testing123
```

and i received "Access-Accept".

But when i tried to connect through captive portal with the same credential, it authenticate via PAP cause the password that saved in **radpostauth** table is saved as clear text, this mean that radius is authenticated via PAP.

i also read that in file **sites-enabled/default** in the *Authentication* section

> This section lists which modules are available for authentication.
>     Note that it does NOT mean 'try each module in order'.  It means
>    that a module from the 'authorize' section adds a configuration
>    attribute 'Auth-Type := FOO'.  That authentication type is then
>    used to pick the appropriate module from the list below.

and when i try to add

```
Auth-Type := CHAP
```

inside authenticate to be like this

```
authenticate 
{
     Auth-Type := CHAP
}
```

it gives me an error

```
/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default[452]: Entry is not a reference to a module
/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default[444]: Errors parsing authenticate section.
```

So where i should tell radius to authenticate with CHAP only ??

Answer (score 0):

Because you've invented syntax instead of following the examples already in the file.

You just need to list:

```
authorize {
    chap
    ...
}

authenticate {
    chap
}
```

And it'll work fine.

If you want to pull records from an sql table

```
authorize {
    update control {
        Cleartext-Password := "%{sql:SELECT <query to get password>}"
    }
    chap
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code, but still not working, the password is saved in **radpostauth**  in clear text.
another question, is the captive portal decide the authentication method or the freeradius?

Comment: Captive portal, unless it's EAP in which case it's negotiated between supplicant and RADIUS server.

Comment: The problem was in the configuration in captive portal, thanks for your help :D